# git patch do not declare a Content-Transfer-Encoding while git send-email

Tags: git, github, patch, git-send-email

I have followed below step.

1. Created a Patch

   git format-patch -1
2. Send that Via git send-email

   git send-email  --subject-prefix="XYZ"  --to=some@email.com   (patch files)

It gives below output

```
The following files are 8bit, but do not declare a Content-Transfer-Encoding.
        0001-xyz.patch
Which 8bit encoding should I declare [UTF-8]? y
Are you sure you want to use <y> [y/N]? y
```

I am not sure what should i give here. I have tried Y & also N here.

3. Open this patch in any EMAIL client (Microsoft Outlook)  & save as .patch
4. Apply that new patch xyz.patch on new git repo. It always get failed as below

   fatal: corrupt patch at line

Any solution to work in this process.

Comment: `[UTF-8]` means it's the default, so just press enter.

Comment: @o11c By just pressing enter also i have same observation

Comment: oh, I think the whole encoding thing is a red herring - likely the real problem is that your "any email client" is junking it. Mozilla Thunderbird is particularly infamous for being impossible to preserve patches in, but many others require significant effort at least.